# Placing interactable views in front of a NavigationView's hidden navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `NavigationView` with a `NavigationButton` inside of it, but I cannot get the NavigationButton to be at the top of the screen and still be able to be pressed, even though the navigation bar is hidden.

This code:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationButton(destination: Text("Button Clicked")) {
                    Text("Hello World")
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Looks like [image: this], but I want it to look like [image: this].

I've tried adding a negative padding to the top of the `VStack` (with `.padding([.top], -95)`, and it visually works, but then I can't interact with the button by tapping it (I think it is behind the hidden navigation bar). I've tried setting the `VStack`'s `zIndex` to 10000 to solve that, but it still didn't work. Is there a way for me to move the button up to the top while still making sure that the button recognizes when it is being tapped?

Comment: The images aren't loading for me, but I'm not sure if it's just because I'm traveling and have bad service. Let me know if anyone can't view the picture and I'll try again once I get better service.

Comment: ^ just fixed the images

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a `navigationBarTitle` before hiding your navigation bar:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationButton(destination: Text("Button Clicked")) {
                    Text("Hello World")
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                }
                Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Title")) // Add this line
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked! Any idea why? Seems like a bug at face value but is there a reason that setting the Nav bar’s title fixed my problem?

Comment: @RPatel99 Yes it's probably a bug but I think a nav bar without a title would not behave correctly and is somehow partial... That might be why it needs a title.

Comment: Doesn't work in Xcode beta 5 (with or without the `navigationbarTitle`

Comment: @tusharsoni1205 try moving the `.navigationBarTitle` inside the NavigationView.

Answer (score 5):

Add this modifier to your NavigationView `edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)`.

Comment: Tried that and it didn’t work. I just pushed the button under the notch (It actually disappeared but I’m assuming it’s under the notch).

Comment: This works but even with using `.top`, it ignores the bottom safe area. Seems like a bug in beta 5